# Python not finding libraries after updating to El Capitan

Tags: python

I have some python scripts that were working fine prior to the OSX update. After the update, they no longer work and return errors saying that some libraries could not be found:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: libevtbin.dylib
Referenced from: ...
Reason: image not found
```

Even though if I ls [path to libraries], 'libLikelihood.dylib' is there. I tried adding this path to my DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH variable also but to no avail. Does anyone know why the library cannot be found? What the the update to to break all this?

Another weird thing is that one of the scripts will give this 'Library not loaded' error if I run it under the 'nice' command, but will run fine without errors if simply run it with 'python script.py'. Other scripts will not run at all in either case though.